# Laravel 5.3 withValidator() was executed before validation ends

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.3

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'some_id' => ['required', 'exists:some_model,id'],
    ];
}

/**
 * Configure the validator instance.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Validation\Validator $validator
 * @return void
 */
public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator->after(function (Validator $validator) {
        if ($this->has('some_id') && Model::find($this->get('some_id'))->eloquent->isBlocked()) {
            throw CustomException();
        }
    });
}
```

- In Laravel docs it is written that withValidator() works after validation is completed. In my case I have a validation rule 'exists' but withValidator() is executed before that so 'exists' rule was ignored here and error is occurring.
- *Any suggestion to fix the issue would be really really helpful. Thanks*

Comment: you misread the documentation .. "This method receives the fully constructed validator, allowing you to call any of its methods before the validation rules are actually evaluated" .... BEFORE

Comment: yes, I have misread that and I thought $validator->after() works only after validation is passed. I added $validator->passes() before that and now it is working properly. Thank You!